# mysqld.exe stop working

Tags: mysql, uwamp

Need your help.
I'm trying to run UwAmp on my pc, everything is working except for MySQL server which keep crashing over and over again. Apache server works well, but when I try to run MySQL server, "mysqld.exe stop working".
And not a single mysql logs.
What is the problem and how can I fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have skype?

Comment: Not on this PC.

Comment: Most likely your local service is running and can cause crash due to clash.

Comment: How can I fix that ?

Comment: Windows event log :
Application défaillante mysqld.exe, version 5.7.11.0, horodatage 0x56affc3f, module défaillant KERNEL32.dll!TryAcquireSRWLockExclusive, version 6.0.6002.19623, horodatage 0x56ec3707, code d’exception 0xc0000139, décalage d’erreur 0x00009f55, ID du processus 0x101c, heure de début de l’application 0x01d26fd16952ac7a.

Answer (score 0):

Possible missing of VC++ 2011, 2013 or 2015 Redist? 
For me, it was the case, because, moreover, I've upgraded Apache to 2.4.25 and MySql to 5.7.17